# Use DB and Session in AuthorizationRequirement class in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have an `AuthorizationRequirement` class like this-

```
internal class ClaimsRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    private readonly EClaim eClaimValue;

    public ClaimsRoleRequirement(object claimValue)
    {
        eClaimValue = (EClaim)claimValue;
        //name = eClaimValue.ToString();
        //description = eClaimValue.Description();
    }
}
```

And I am calling this from `Startup.cs` file like this-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ..................
    ..................
    services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        foreach (object eClaimValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EClaim)))
        {
            options.AddPolicy(eClaimValue.ToString(), policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ClaimsRoleRequirement(eClaimValue)));
        }
    });
}
```

I like to query DB and get the current user from the session in `ClaimsRoleRequirement` class.
Is there any way of doing this?

### Re-

`EClaim` enum is like this-

```
public enum EClaim
{
    [Display(Name = "Role-Claim Policy")]
    [Description("Role-Claim-View")]
    RoleClaimView = 0,
    [Description("Role Create")]
    RoleCreate,
    [Description("Claim Create")]
    ClaimCreate
}
```

My DB context is like this-

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    private string IdentitySchemaName = "Identity";
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment Environment;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        : base(options)
    {
        Environment = env;
        //this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    ........
    ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The authorization requirement, `ClaimsRoleRequirement` in your case, is just meant as some kind of a marker that specifies that this requirement is needed for a user to access a resource. However, it is not the job of the requirement to specify *how* this requirement is verified for a user.

To evaluate the requirement, you will need to create an [authorization handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorization-handlers) for your requirement. The authorization will then get called when the authorization system is evaluating the requirement and the handler gets a chance of evaluating it. As part of that process, the handler can also access request-specific information, e.g. from the session, or query other services to retrieve further information.

The handler for your requirement could for example look like this:

```
public class ClaimsRoleAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ClaimsRoleRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ClaimsRoleAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ClaimsRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var user = context.User;
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var session = httpContext.Session;
        var db = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        // do stuff

        // finally, call Succeed for the requirement if the user fulfills the requirement
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

That being said, when using ASP.NET Core Identity and you just want to verify the *roles* or custom claims of your identity, you won’t need to make a round-trip to your database in order to verify these requirement. Configured roles of your identity will automatically be added as role claims and custom claims you configured for the application user will also be available on the claims principal itself. So you should be able to verify these by doing something like `context.User.IsInRole(roleName)` or `context.User.HasClaim(claimType)`.